Filter function for column with values only
I have a master database that lists the company with associated products and the clinical trial phase the product is in for different diseases. I am trying to only pull in columns that have values in them from the master tab. If there are no values, that column should not show (I do not want a blank column to appear). I also want to add the column header to be included.


What have you tried so far?

Is there only a single company on your Master Tab?

You could try using the following formula:


=TOROW(IF(($H3=$A3)*($I3=$B$3:$B$6)*($C$3:$E$6<>""),$C$2:$E$2&" "&$C$3:$E$6,NA()),2)



Thanks for the response! I am using the formula below, but it is not pulling the right data. I can't seem to add an image. =TOROW(IF(($D2='I&I Landscape Tracker'!$E$4:$E$455) * ('I&I Landscape Tracker'!$H$3:$CM$455 <> ""), 'I&I Landscape Tracker'!$H$2:$CM$2 & " - " & 'I&I Landscape Tracker'!$H$3:$CM$455, NA()), 2)

@bug17 without sample data it is very hard to say, for me it is working very clearly. see what you are missing by evaluating the formula
